# How to access the function of ethereum contract using web3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have written a basic hello world! smart contract and deployed using testrpc and truffle. I have a function in the contract that returns a value and i am using this function and the value it returns to display the value in webpage using react and java script code.Codes are below

1. Greeter.sol

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Greeter{
    string greeting;
    function greeter(string memory _greeting) public{
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet()public view returns(string memory){
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

2. EthereumSetup.js

---

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
    const web3 = new Web3( new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://localhost:8545"));
    let greeterABI = [ { constant: false,
        inputs: [ [Object] ],
        name: 'greeter',
        outputs: [],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'function',
        signature: '0xfaf27bca' },
      { constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: 'greet',
        outputs: [ [Object] ],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        signature: '0xcfae3217' } ];
    let greeterAddress = '0x52F2Ce3bB739567a05AA4eA36720028946c46C5f';
    const greeterContract = web3.eth.Contract(greeterABI,greeterAddress);
    
    export{greeterContract};
```

### 3.App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {greeterContract} from './EthereumSetup';
import Web3 from 'web3'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      greeting: ""
    }
  }
 async componentWillMount(){
    
      var data =await greeterContract.methods.greet().call()
      
    this.setState({
      greeting: String(data)
    })
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            <h2>"{this.state.greeting}"</h2>
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

I have running testrpc and npn start to load the webpage its all going fine
I opened the truffle console and gave commands to set the value of the variable and even invoked the greet()(function that returns value) its image is here [Truffle console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AksOJ.png)

Before calling greeter function with value to set i get nothing like [value of variable before assigning value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC01J.png)

I know there is some error in  componentWillMount() of App.js file which is making my web page blank.

I know testrpc is quite outdated

Comment: You did not import `web3` in `App.js`

Comment: My bad i pasted wrong code. I did import it now though i did not use it anywhere.

Comment: Can you log and show us what your getting for data before calling set state?

Comment: added a image as requested @LucasHendren

Comment: So I not actually seeing where your setting the return value to something that isnt blank

Comment: In the first picture that i added i had called the function greeter which sets the value after setting the value i am calling greet function which returns the value set earlier ( "Hello World " was the message set and i got the same in return when i called the greet function)